# Magento-2.1 : Warning: Missing argument 2 for OAuth\Common\Consumer\Credentials::__construct()

Tags: magento-2.1, setup-di-compile

I have used below code, it's working in Magento-2.2 but not working in Magento-2.1 after code compilation.

```
public function __construct(
        \OAuth\Common\Consumer\CredentialsFactory $credentialsFactory
    ) {
        $this->credentialsFactory = $credentialsFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       $credentials = $this->credentialsFactory->create([
        'consumerId' => $this->helper->getConsumerId('facebook'),
        'consumerSecret' => $this->helper->getConsumerSecret('facebook'),
        'callbackUrl' => $this->helper->getAuthUrl('facebook')
        ]);
    }
```

if I deleted var/di & var/generation it's working, if I compiled code in 2.1.x then it's throw below error.

> Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Missing argument 2 for
> OAuth\Common\Consumer\Credentials::__construct(), called in
> /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
> on line 93 and defined in
> /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/lusitanian/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Consumer/Credentials.php
> on line 30
>
> ## 0 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/lusitanian/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Consumer/Credentials.php(30):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Missing argumen...',
> '/var/www/html/m...', 30, Array)
>
> ## 1 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93):
>
> OAuth\Common\Consumer\Credentials->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
>
> ## 2 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('OAuth\Common\Co...',
>
> Array)
>
> ## 3 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57):
>
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('OAuth\Common\Co...',
> Array)
>
> ## 4 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/var/generation/OAuth/Common/Consumer/CredentialsFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('OAuth\Common\Co...',
>
> Array)
>
> ## 5 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/app/code/Magedelight/ModuleName/Controller/Facebook/Login.php(84):
>
> OAuth\Common\Consumer\CredentialsFactory->create(Array)
>
> ## 6 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102):
>
> Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login->execute()
>
> ## 7 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 8 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>
> Array)
>
> ## 9 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magedelight\Soc...',
>
> 'dispatch',
> Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
> Array, 'contextPlugin')
>
> ## 10 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 11 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
>
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 12 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magedelight\Soc...',
>
> 'dispatch',
> Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
> Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
>
> ## 13 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 14 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
>
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 15 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magedelight\Soc...',
>
> 'dispatch',
> Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
> Array, 'storeCheck')
>
> ## 16 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 17 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
>
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 18 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magedelight\Soc...',
>
> 'dispatch',
> Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
> Array, 'weee-app-action...')
>
> ## 19 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 20 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
>
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 21 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magedelight\Soc...',
> 'dispatch',
> Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
> Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
>
> ## 22 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91):
>
> Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 23 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142):
>
> Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor),
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 24 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/var/generation/Magedelight/ModuleName/Controller/Facebook/Login/Interceptor.php(26):
>
> Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> Array, Array)
>
> ## 25 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
>
> Magedelight\ModuleName\Controller\Facebook\Login\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 26 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 27 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>
> Array)
>
> ## 28 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...',
>
> 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
> Array, 'requestPreproce...')
>
> ## 29 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 30 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 31 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...',
>
> 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
> Array, 'install')
>
> ## 32 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 33 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 34 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...',
>
> 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
> Array, 'front-controlle...')
>
> ## 35 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 36 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 37 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...',
> 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
> Array, 'front-controlle...')
>
> ## 38 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 39 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142):
>
> Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 40 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> Array, Array)
>
> ## 41 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 42 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
>
> ## 43 /var/www/html/magento-2.1.11-demo/index.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>
> ## 44 {main}

How I can resolve this issue for Magento-2.1.x? Any one have solution or idea?

Comment: can you please share your error log file code?

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: @SureshChikani Magento ver 1.9.2.3,I am work with REST API in POSTMAN, i have all oAuth 1.0 details like Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Token Secret. Now i moved to oAuth 2.0, how can i get my all oAuth 2.0 details?

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
<?php
use OAuth\Common\Consumer\Credentials;

class Yourclassname
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $credentials = new Credentials($this->helper->getConsumerId('facebook'), $this->helper->getConsumerSecret('facebook'), $this->helper->getAuthUrl('facebook'));
    }

}
```

Reference from,

```
vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/api-functional/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Authentication/OauthHelper.php
```

Comment: as per above code, without array how can pass array argument?

Comment: @SureshChikani Please check updated answer.

Comment: I already check this reference but As per magento marketplace standards we cannot instantiate object of class as above.